# APNS - Node APN - payload - single quote

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose, apple-push-notifications

I am testing push notification using the node-apn module in node js. All works fine except that special characters such as a single quote does not properly escape. The push notification with a single quote (i.e. we'll becomes we\'ll in the actual notification). I tried regex, mongoose.toObject, message.message.toString() to no avail.

```
Message.findOne(query).lean().exec(function (err, doc){

     if (!doc || doc == null) {                                              
                    message.save(function(e) {
                        console.log("message saved")
                        if (e) {
                            console.log("there is an error")
                            console.log(e)
                        } else {

                            console.log(message.device_token)

                            var mesg = message.toObject();
                            var msg = JSON.stringify(mesg);
                            var payload = {
                                "contact" : message.contact,
                                "did" : message.did,
                                "id" : message.message_id,
                                "date" : message.date,
                                "message" : message.message
                            }     

                            var clean = message.message.toString().replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");

                            var note = new apns.Notification();
                            var myDevice = new apns.Device(message.device_token);
                        note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
                        note.badge = 3;                                                                 
                        note.alert = message.message;
                        note.payload = payload;
                        apnsConnection.pushNotification(note, myDevice);                                                                    
                    }
                    })                                                                                                                                                                                    
        }                                                                                                                                                               
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by escaping the json formmatted single quote (which was //') in the message.message value using the replace function:

```
var messageStringCleaned = message.message.toString().replace(/\\/g,"");                                                                                                                                                                            

    var payload = {
        "contact" : message.contact,
        "did" : message.did,
        "id" : message.message_id,
        "date" : message.date,
        "message" : messageStringCleaned
    }     

var note = new apns.Notification();
var myDevice = new apns.Device(message.device_token);
note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
note.badge = 3;                                                                 
note.alert = messageStringCleaned;
note.payload = payload;
apnsConnection.pushNotification(note, myDevice);
```